# What does ActiveX in ADO.NET implies?

Tags: ado.net

I have read somewhere that ADO.NET uses XML to transport data . Is it true? Because of it the name ActiveX comes into existence?

Comment: I can't make sense of this. I can't imagine what you would read about ADO.NET and/or XML that would lead you to any conclusion about ActiveX. Can you do more than just "read somewhere" and provide a link?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: http://jenny.sybay.com/dotnet/techtalk/techtalk5/adonet.ppt,

Comment: slide No. 4.(why ado.net?).

Comment: I see no references to ActiveX at all in that presentation

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: oops!but can u tell me what is activeX in ADO.NEt does is indicates an upgraded version. Also please answer that do it uses XML only to transport the data from database to dataset. Also in what format does the data in dataset gets stored. Thank u..

Comment: Please answer that do ADO.NET uses XML only to transport the data from database to dataset . In which format does the data stored in dataset.(if in XML?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name ADO stands for [ActiveX Data Objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActiveX_Data_Objects). ADO was used in the old COM (a.k.a. ActiveX; ActiveX is a loose collection of various COM/OLE technologies, branded so by Microsoft) based world to access databases. [ADO.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET) is the name for the .NET counterpart, but it has no longer any connection to ActiveX.

The name ActiveX has no connection to XML at all. XML is used by the DataSet for transferring [DiffGrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172088.aspx) internally in the application, but the transfer of data in the built in data providers in ADO.NET doesn't use any XML when transferring data from the database to the client to my knowledge.

Also see [this comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ADO_and_ADO.NET) between ADO and ADO.NET.

Regarding the [internal representation/implementation](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Data/System/Data/DataSet@cs/1305376/DataSet@cs) of a DataSet, it's just a collection of DataTables, DataRelation and other .NET classes. The XML that can be imported/exported is produced by serialization.

Comment: Added info on internal representation of DataSets